# Summing the number of multiples in a column in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a macro (or query) in access that will sum the number of duplicate values in a column, and preserve those values in a new table, with the number of duplicates next to it.

So, for example, I would have an unordered column with 10 values, 6 are "option 1", 3 are "option 2" and 1 is "option 3".

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 1
Option 1
Option 2
Option 1
Option 2
Option 1
Option 1
```

I'd like to be able to parse that into a 3 x 2 table of:

```
Option 1 | 6
Option 2 | 3
Option 3 | 1
```

In this case, the data is unordered, but I could conceivably order the data in the query. I'll be wanting to do this to multiple columns. Is there a way to program in the Visual basic editor in access to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a query like this assuming you have source and target tables defined:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTbl
SELECT OptionCol, COUNT(*)
  FROM SourceTbl
GROUP BY OptionCol
```

If you want to insert only duplicates (I do this a lot in Access), add a `HAVING` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTbl
SELECT OptionCol, COUNT(*)
  FROM SourceTbl
GROUP BY OptionCol
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that is very helpful. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes.